# Can't grab usermeta description variable in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Accessing the usermeta description field for the current user in worpress is being finicky with me. I am using description as a bio field. Here is what I have below. The display name part works fine, but not so much with getting the description. I know that $bio[0]->description is incorrect, but it is the last thing I tried before posting here. Maybe I'm just tired...

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$bio = get_usermeta( $current_user, $description ); 

echo 'Your Name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
?>

Your Bio: <?php echo $bio[0]->description ?>
```

Comment: so what's the problem? what's not working? when debugging, enable php error reporting first. and `<?php echo $bio[0]->description ?>` is missing `;` (maybe a typo?)

Comment: I get "Array" which means it is close. It is returning the data for the user's description but not the text stored in the description variable. And yes, I do have the ; in my code.

Comment: try to diagnose: check with `print_r()` or `var_dump($bio)`

Comment: i don't use wordpress, but the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_usermeta) clearly states that you provide `get_usermeta()` with and `ID (int)` and the `metakey (string)`. so maybe `echo $bio = get_usermeta($current_user->id, 'description');`

Comment: Well, it is grabbing the array as I mentioned but I'm having trouble echoing the array. Did the vardump and it is a 27 item array. You can see that item number 4 in the array is the bio. But there will be thousands of items in this array soon so I don't want to do something like echo $bio[0][4]. It needs to be scaleable and more elegant echo.    array(27) {
[0]=>
NULL
[1]=>
NULL
[2]=>
string(8) “user2″
[3]=>
string(27) “This is my short bio”

Comment: What i mean was echo $bio[3]; will return the bio data. But that is just a quick fix for this example. There will be thousands of records in the user_meta table and I need to return the description variable for the current user dynamically (without knowing the variable's position in the array) which I thought I did with my $current user, $description.

Comment: sorry man i don't understand you at all or what is the end goal here, i don't understand why you're indicating that `$bio` will contain thousands of entries since it only gets the data of the current/particular user. `echo $bio[3];` should be enough. and fyi, says in the manual this function is already deprecated.

Comment: That's it Ghost! echo $bio = get_usermeta($current_user->id, 'description'); How do I approve a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly states in the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_usermeta):

```
<?php get_usermeta( $userid, $metakey ); ?>
```

You need to feed it with the `$userid` (user's id), and the particular `$metakey`.

Sample Usage:

```
echo $bio = get_usermeta($current_user->id, 'description');
```

FYI: It is also said in the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) that this function is `deprecated`.

Try this instead:

```
echo $bio = get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'description');
```

Comment: Great. But FYI, using the get_user_meta returns "array" and not the value of the variable. It works with get_usermeta. Sometimes older is better or whatever adage you want to use...